# android layout does not scrolls up when softkey is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, manifest

I have set the windowSoftInput to adjustResize, but yet the keypad hides the textinput

this is my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.41"
        android:background="@drawable/username_textbox"
        android:ems="10"
        android:minWidth="110dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/password_icon" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/username_textbox"
        android:ems="10"
        android:minWidth="110dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_signin"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="207dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: default state]

[image: hides the edittext]

Answer (score 2):

I used like this. It works fine.

```
private int mSoftKeyboardHeight = 0;



protected void scrollDownOnKeyboardPopUp() {

    mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int keyBoardHeight = 0;
                    if (keyBoardHeight <= 100) {
                        Rect r = new Rect();
                        mScrollView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                        int screenHeight = mScrollView.getRootView().getHeight();
                        mSoftKeyboardHeight = screenHeight - (r.bottom - r.top);
                        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height",
                                "dimen", "android");
                        if (resourceId > 0) {
                            mSoftKeyboardHeight -= getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                                    resourceId);
                        }
                        if (mSoftKeyboardHeight > 100) {
                            keyBoardHeight = mSoftKeyboardHeight;
                        }
                        mScrollView.scrollTo(mScrollView.getScrollY(), mSoftKeyboardHeight
                                + mBottomFunctionPanel.getHeight() + mChatEditPanel.getHeight()
                                + mScrollView.getScrollY());
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Then where you need just call it.

```
scrollDownOnKeyboardPopUp();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">` instead of `adjustResize`.

`adjustResize`, as the name says, resizes the window to make room for the soft keyboard, but in your case there's enough room. `adjustPan` scrolls the window so that the focused view stays visible.